# .NET cannot locate unmanaged DLL in same directory

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, dll

I have a C++ DLL library (let's call it `unmanaged.dll`) that gets wrapped around a managed .NET library (let's call it `managed.dll`). The `managed.dll` uses `unmanaged.lib` to import/link `unmanaged.dll`. I have another ASP.NET Web API project that uses `managed.dll` (let's call the project `webapi.dll`). Now, whenever I build the Web project, in the output directory I get `webapi.dll` and `managed.dll`. Then, I manually copy `unmanaged.dll` to be in the same output folder so that (presumably) .NET can locate it and load it.
However, when I try to run `webapi.dll`, it fails with an error that it cannot load `managed.dll`:

> Could not load file or assembly 'managed.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

This is particularly weird because `unmanaged.dll` is in the same folder.
What I find very weird is that if I put `unmanaged.dll` under `C:\Windows\system32` then .NET can properly load it!

My question is how can I make this `unmanaged.dll` visible to .NET in the folder where the .NET project output is residing?

Comment: The OS has no reason whatsoever to look in the same directory as the .NET assembly for this file.  Above all because it is completely unaware of what the CLR or your program does.  The usual workaround is to pinvoke SetDllDirectory() but that might not be a fantastic idea on a web server.  Adding the directory to the PATH might be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the IIS that is causing the problems. Had the same problem, sovled it by adding the dll to a folder, that lies in the PATH variable.

Comment: Just to add to the comment, for anyone facing a similar issue, on your Web API project in Global.asax under Application_Start(), you should put something like this: `var path = string.Concat(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH"), ";", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath);
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", path, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);` This will help locate your libraries in the same folder